# Read input from stdin as well as ready to receive broadcast from server

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, broadcast

I have a server who listens from connected clients and broadcast it to all other connected clients. But on other side client should listen to the broadcast server is sending as well as it must be able to read input from stdin and send to server for broadcast. I'm bit confused. I'm doing this in c++.

Comment: have a look at multithreading, gather the input data from separate threads, use message passing or events to give the data to a sending thread

Comment: that means i'll have to wake up thread in round robin method. One to check for input from STDIN and other from server??

Comment: Both calls to wait for server data and stdin will block, and automatically wake the thread up as data comes ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 kind of patterns how to do read from multiple file descriptors

- use threads as Phil Williams proposed
- use a poling mechanism like `select()` or `poll()`.

Using `select()` or `poll()` is a better approach for your problem I think.

Sets of file descriptors are arguments passed to `select()` and it waits till one of them is prepared for reading or writing. There are a plenty of examples on internet how to use `select()`.